# what is happening between AspNetStart and AspNetAppDomainEnter in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, iis-7

I enabled Failed Request Tracing on my IIS7 website for a particular ashx and found that most of the time it returns in 16ms or so, occasionally it would take over 2000ms to return. The Failed Request Tracing logs indicate that this time is lost between the 'AspNetStart' event and the 'AspNetAppDomainEnter' event. Does anyone know what its doing?

Many Thanks!

Comment: MSDN support said that this delay is simply part of the queuing between those two parts of the process and that a 2 second delay was not unusual but that a 10 second delay would merit more investigation. They said that there weren't any settings that I could change to reduce that delay.

Comment: The real question is: Does such a delay have any real effect on the page-execution-time? Just for clarification: If I have a delay of 2 seconds between those 2 steps/phases, do I also have a 2 seconds longer page-execution-time? Did they give you any hints where/how to investigate if the delay is gte 10 seconds, or did they leave that open?

Comment: Yes, the user had to wait 2 seconds for the page to return to them. Naa, they just said that they would investigate further if my delay was more significant.